# Where do I set my iPhone App's version?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, info.plist

The only place I can think to change is the version in my Target Properties. However, I would assume this is supposed to go somewhere in my Info.plist file as well?

If not, how can I read this version info into my app at runtime (if it's in the plist somewhere, that's no problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I spoke too soon. Changing it in my Target's Get Info pane did in fact update the Info.plist file, under the key "CFBundleVersion".